# Syntax Issue With MySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER update_cnitrand_cust_code AFTER INSERT ON `cnitrand`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE bill_no INT DEFAULT 0;

    IF NEW.bill_no = 0 THEN
        SET bill_no = (SELECT bill_no FROM cnitrand 
                       WHERE (tx_no = NEW.tx_no AND 
                              input_area = NEW.input_area AND 
                              tx_line_no = NEW.tx_line_no AND 
                              bill_no <> "") OR 
                             (tx_no = NEW.tx_no AND 
                              bill_no <> "") 
                       LIMIT 1);
    ELSE
        SET bill_no = NEW.bill_no;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO tblrptcnitrandmap 
    (tx_no, input_area, tx_line_no, bill_cust_code, bill_no) 
    VALUES 
    (NEW.tx_no, NEW.input_area, NEW.tx_line_no, NEW.bill_cust_code, bill_no);

END;$$
```

It returns an error

> "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'$$'` at line 14"

Can you please tell me, what is wrong with code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER update_cnitrand_cust_code AFTER INSERT ON `cnitrand`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE bill_no INT DEFAULT 0;

    IF NEW.bill_no = 0 THEN
        SET bill_no = (SELECT bill_no FROM cnitrand WHERE (tx_no = NEW.tx_no AND input_area = NEW.input_area AND tx_line_no = NEW.tx_line_no AND bill_no <> "") OR (tx_no = NEW.tx_no AND bill_no <> "") LIMIT 1);
    ELSE
        SET bill_no = NEW.bill_no;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO tblrptcnitrandmap (tx_no, input_area, tx_line_no, bill_cust_code, bill_no) VALUES (NEW.tx_no, NEW.input_area, NEW.tx_line_no, NEW.bill_cust_code, bill_no);

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Why do you think `END;$$` was wrong and `END$$ DELIMITER;` is correct?

Comment: Refer to [*Stored Procedures - MySQL*](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-storedprocedures.pdf‎)